# Using Ampscript to grab First Name when have full name in a field

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have a triggered send going out, and am getting a field called "CustomerFullName" the data comes in as LastName, FirstName MiddleInitial

How can I use Ampscript to just pull the firstname?

Comment: If I were you, I would start by reading up on Substring and Indexof functions in Ampscript reference

Answer (score 2):

This comes directly from the [ampscript.guide](https://ampscript.guide/substring/), like Lukas said, you need to use the Substring function  to cut everything after the first space:

```
%%[

var @fullName
var @firstName

set @fullName = AttributeValue("fullName") /* value from attribute or DE column in send context */
set @fullName = "Curt Harris" /* or a literal value */

if indexOf(@fullName, " ") > 0 then
  set @firstName = Substring(@fullName,1, Subtract(IndexOf(@fullName," "),1))
endif

]%%
fullName: %%=v(@fullName)=%%
<br>firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

So in your case, it would be:

```
%%[

var @fullName
var @firstName

set @fullName = AttributeValue("CustomerFullName") 

if indexOf(@fullName, " ") > 0 then
  set @firstName = Substring(@fullName,1, Subtract(IndexOf(@fullName," "),1))
endif

]%%
fullName: %%=v(@fullName)=%%
<br>firstName: %%=v(@firstName)=%%
```

Comment: If you look carefully, OP needs to use IndexOf twice: first to find "," after last name, then " " after first name :-)

Answer (score 2):

This may be a bit of overkill but as long as you can validate that the structure/format of the full name is the same, you can use this snippet to ensure you get the full first name and not just the first 'part'.

I say this because there are people out there that have names like 'Mary Anne' where that is their first name, not 'Mary'. And that can be a sore point at times with people, so it is something to avoid.

All that being said too, I would greatly recommend getting this resolved prior to send time and have the data correct if possible, but this should help in the short term.

```ampscript
%%[
SET @name = "Farnsworth, Hubert Jeremy J."

SET @nameRS = BuildRowsetFromString(@name,",")

SET @fmName = Field(Row(@nameRS,2),1)

SET @fmNameRS = BuildRowsetFromString(@fmName," ")

FOR @i=1 TO Subtract(RowCount(@fmNameRS),1) DO
  if @i > 1 THEN
    SET @space = " "
  endif
  SET @Fname = CONCAT(@Fname,@space,Field(Row(@fmNameRS,@i),1))
NEXT @i
]%%

%%=v(@Fname)=%%
```

Which would output:

```
Hubert Jeremy
```

And this even has the flexibility if they don't use initial, but instead use the full name, or if they do not use a period, but just a leter or alternate across, etc.

This will NOT be able to handle a different format of the name being passed in though. If the name is passed as "Hubert Jeremy J. Farnsworth" then this will fail and fail hard.